# How to add large numbers with PHP?

Tags: php, addition

I'm trying to add 76561197960265728 and 81665865 which equal 76561198041931593. When I do this in PHP I get 7.6561198041932E+16.

I need to get the full number with no commas and without it being in scientific notation so I can attach the number to the end of a string. `bcadd()` doesn't seem to work either. I was using `bcadd()` incorrectly, I hadn't noticed it needed strings and not ints. The correct way to use `bcadd()` is `bcadd("76561197960265728","81665865")` whereas I was trying to do `bcadd(76561197960265728,81665865)` , Note the quotations.

Comment: Then don't use integers and floats, which have limitations on computer systems; but use strings with [bcmath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).... but bcadd() expects input values to be strings - [demo](http://ideone.com/OdHA6I)

Comment: bcadd worked fine for me, but like Mark Baker said, it takes strings as arguments, not integer/float values. http://codepad.viper-7.com/nucnDc

Comment: Can we see your `bcadd` code that didn't work, edited into the question? That would probably be the best way forward (and to prevent the question from being placed on-hold).

Answer (score -2):

Use `printf()` to print your numeric variable in a particular format.

Use `sprint()` to assign your numeric variable to a string variable in a particular format.